# Does "hardly consistent" mean "not consistent at all"?

Tags: meaning

> That is **hardly consistent** with fundamental tax reform.

Does "hardly consistent" mean "not consistent at all"?

Answer (score 1):

It literally means 'so little consistent as not to be significant' - but *hardly* can be used as a sarcastic way of implying 'not at all'.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of consistent is *inconsistent*, but even then it isn't as strong as some antonyms.

"Consistent" in this context means *compatible with*, or *in keeping with* something else. Something that was "consistent with fundamental tax reform" would meet all or nearly all the requirements. Something that was "inconsistent" could just be out of step in some fundamental way, but not necessarily every single way.

"Hardly consistent", or "not consistent" doesn't seem quite as strong as "inconsistent" - it might suggest that it is either a little out of step, or perhaps going in a different direction.